# How to deny access to a certain HTML file

Tags: nginx, html

I know how to deny access to all websites but I want to know how to deny access to an IP to the website test.html using NGINX

Answer (score 2):

You can define a location for an individual URI by using the `location =` form.

```
location = /test.html {
    allow 1.2.3.4;
    deny all;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You need a location block in your config like this

```
location = /test.html {
        deny 192.168.1.1; #define the IP you want to block here
        allow all; #allow the rest
}
```

[Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) tests IP in order and accepts the first match, so in this case your denied IP will match the first entry and all others will match the `allow all`